# In V8, what's the max value of call stack?

Tags: javascript, v8

Just curious about it. It will be great if you also tell me where to find the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean stack trace limit:

You can check this by running the following in your console:

```
Error.stackTraceLimit
```

You can also increase that limit by setting it to a different value in your script, or by passing the following argument to Chrome while launching it from command line:

```
--js-flags="--stack-trace-limit <value>"
```

If you mean general stack trace:

I think it depends on the application using the V8 engine.
E.g. for node JS, it's an option you can set:

```
$ node --v8-options | grep stack_size -A 1
--stack_size (default size of stack region v8 is allowed to use (in kBytes))
    type: int  default: 984
```

Comment: I don't mean debug trace stack, just call stack. Such as recursive call stack.

Comment: Edited answer with both answers